# Trying to remember a poem that I only have a snippet of

Tags: identification-request, poetry

I'm trying to find some lost poems that were favorites of mine in high school. This one, I only have one line that I remember clearly. Not much to go on, I know, but if anyone recognizes it, I would be grateful. Thanks! The line I remember is as follows, and I believe it is the starting line:

> Today I thought about how much you really mean to me, and I felt it so deep.

Sitting here thinking about it, I've got a line to add, that I think is accurate, but not 100% sure. It goes as such:

> I try to think, that it might be in the way your eyes smile

Comment: So sitting here thinking about it, I've got a line to add, that I think is accurate, but not 100% sure. It goes as such:

Comment: Sorry, hit the wrong button... Line is:

Comment: I try to think, that it might be in the way your eyes smile

Comment: You can always [edit] your own question if you remember additional information :-) Some other useful datapoints here would be when and where you were in high school - at least in which country and which decade, to narrow the search for when and where this poem might have been published.